# Handling empty values and rows in csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with columns: part No, name, weight, width, height, length, price.

Part No, name and price are obligatory values. There are some empty rows like ';;;;;;' and I can skip them while reading the file. But there are some rows that have no 'name' or 'price' value. How can I skip them?

```
def get_part_list(csv_filename):
    part_list = []
    with open(csv_filename) as csv_fd:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_fd, delimiter=';')
        next(reader)
        try:
            for row in reader:
                if (row is not None) and (row[1] is not None) and (row[6] is not None):
                    part_list.append(row)
        except (IndexError, ValueError):
            next(reader)
return part_list
```

As I wrote in the beginning, I get a list without empty rows, but there are some rows with empty 'name' and 'price' like:

```
12345,,10 kg,,,,145.00
789,spindle,0.5kg,,,,,
```

Comment: Are commas really the stand ins for the missing names and prices?

Comment: Ann Zen - yes they are.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split each row by a `,` in order to use your subscriptions:

```
with open('f.txt', 'r') as f:
    rows = [row for row in f if row]

part_list = []
for row in rows:
    row = row.split(',')
    try:
        if row[1] and row[6]:
            part_list.append(row)
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        pass
```